# Error: This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb

I'm trying to run this query in `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.44-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1` but got this error all the time:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_companies_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `companies`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
[Err] 1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

What this means? How I can avoid and/or fix it?

This is the queries I am trying to execute:

```
-- brands
ALTER TABLE `brands`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_brands_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `brands`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- companies
ALTER TABLE `companies`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_companies_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `companies`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- emails
ALTER TABLE `emails`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_emails_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `emails`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- events_tracking
ALTER TABLE `events_tracking`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_events_tracking_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `events_tracking`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- media
ALTER TABLE `media`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_media_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `media`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- messages
ALTER TABLE `messages`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_messages_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `messages`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- reps
ALTER TABLE `reps`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_reps_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `reps`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- targets
ALTER TABLE `targets`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_targets_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `targets`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
-- territories
ALTER TABLE `territories`
  CHANGE COLUMN `createdAt` `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CHANGE COLUMN `updatedAt` `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_territories_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `territories`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
```

Comment: Add the `SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();` to the existing triggers.

Comment: Starting with MariaDB 10.2.3 you can have multiple triggers for the same trigger_time and trigger_event. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-trigger/

Comment: Just to add to @cgaldiolo MySQL 5.7.2 also supports multiple triggers for the same action time and event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means you already have an `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on `companies` table.

If it is the same trigger (meaning `trig_companies_table_insert`) that you created earlier and now you want to replace it then you need to drop it first:

```
DROP TRIGGER trig_companies_table_insert;
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE TRIGGER trig_companies_table_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `companies`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.createdAt = NOW();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now if you have some other trigger you have to merge code from both triggers into one, then drop existing trigger, and then create a new one.

To show the list of existing triggers use SHOW TRIGGERS.

```
SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `table` = 'companies';
```

Answer (score 2):

It means you already have a trigger for `BEFORE INSERT ON companies`.
 (action time = `BEFORE`, event = `INSERT`)
You can't have two of them for the same event and action time.

You can fix it by editing the existing `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Yet another absolutely shocking indictment of MySQL. Not sure about PostgreSQL, but Interbase/Firebird has had multiple triggers on all actions for at least two decades <shakes head in disbelief>.

Comment: @Vérace I find this the least of MySQL problems.

Comment: Agreed - it's just yet another gripe I have. If you look for books about MySQL on Amazon, you get 4429 results, PostgreSQL 620 & Firebird/Interbase 63. That speaks for itself - two vastly superior databases trailing miserably in terms of popularity and usage.

Comment: @Vérace, not sure about the two decades for PostgreSQL but at least version 7.1 from 2001 had support for multiple triggers.

Comment: I was sure of it - I just wasn't sure of the date. I was working with Interbase approx. 2 decades ago, so I was certain of my ground on that one.